# Good source book for wilderness/road encounters?

Tags: game-recommendation, osr, encounters

I'm a GM and like for my players to have several interesting encounters when making long road journeys between cities. I especially enjoy when the party has options of how to deal with what they encounter, rather than killing everything that moves. Moral ambiguity is interesting too.  I'm not a fan of rolling on a wilderness encounter table and coming up with "4 goblins" or "6 wolves".  I know, I know, I can flesh it out myself, but often do not have time to prepare.

So I'm looking for a good resource, and one that is preferably of the dead tree variety.  I think Johnn Four's "100 Roadside Encounter Ideas" has a lot of good stuff in it, especially since many of the encounters are (probably) non-combat, but I'd like to see ideas like these fleshed out into a one page per encounter format, or something similar.  Pretty much any fantasy RPG system is acceptable.  Please help!

To hopefully make my question clearer, I am looking for a pre-made roadside/wilderness encounters (not Encounters) book that I can use in my OSR game.  Something more fleshed out than a wandering monster table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've gotten a lot of mileage (har, har) out of [Atlas Games' En Route series from their Penumbra line for 3e D&D](http://www.atlas-games.com/penumbra/).  There's 3 in the series and they're more than one page each, probably an 8 page mini-adventure each on average.

Harder to get but more totally on point is the AD&D [Book of Lairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Book_of_Lairs), full of one page (sometimes two, for especially large groups like the 251 hobgoblins that merit a map) fleshed out random encounter/lairs for use on treks. There was a Book of Lairs II as well I think. They're not on dndclassics.com however so may take some doing to obtain.

Unfortunately these are light on the flavor/non-combat encounters so I'd like to hear other resources as well.  I always want some big ol' encounter tables full of random fluff as well as Monster Encounters (tm) on my wilderness travel games, and though there have been a couple charts like that made for specific adventures over time, it's pretty rare and ends up being mostly "roll percentile to determine monster."

Comment: I independently discovered the En Route books and bought #1 and #3.  They are really good, and I especially like the "Hell Cow" encounter.  As you said, they are a little longer than I would ideally like, but still very good.  I would have never thought to look at the Book of Lairs, so thank you!  I am about to order!

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to take a look at the WFRP 2E [WFRP GM Pack and Toolkit](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/63139/WFRP-GM-Pack-and-Toolkit?affiliate_id=188022) (PDF $5US, but printable to meet the dead tree criteria). I've used this several times in my campaign for short RP sessions.

Samples from the *Wilderness Encounters* section include:

> **01-05**
>   Around a bend in the road a travelling tinker trudges into view, his
>   wares clanking on his back. The tinker, whose name is Waldemar, is
>   more than happy to offer his services to the characters, and for a few
>   pennies will mend their broken buckles, knives, pots and cups.

or

> **56-60**
>   The characters run into a fleeing man, dressed only in his
>   undergarments. He pleads for their help but a few minutes later an
>   angry torch waving mob appear on his heels screaming something about
>   the village elder’s daughter.

### System Context Tips

There are GM tips for running the encounters in a WFRP 2E System Context. **I think this is important** because presenting the System Context in such a way provides the OSR GM a context framing for *their favorite OSR rule set*.

### Encounter Settings

The following encounter settings are provided for the GM in a randomized table for each setting:

**Cities of the Empire**

- Building and Establishments
- We Don't Go Into the Sewers (brief ideas about fantasy sewers)
- Street Encounters
- Thieves and Beggars (tips for thief and beggar encounters)
- Inns of the Empire (20 inns and taverns)
- Bugman's Pub Rules (three (3) simple tavern gambling games)

**The Great Wilds**

- Roads, Forests, and Farms
- Natural Hazards
- Wilderness Encounters
- Outlaws and Animals
- Villages, Towns, and Settlements
- Something Strange

I have used the *GM Toolkit* effectively to seed a number of RP encounters, even established a small campaign in a border village where Orcs and provincial politics threatened to start a civil war.

Answer (score 2):

There's a [fan made module for Hârn called 101 encounters](http://www.lythia.com/adventures/101-encounters/) which can be used for any setting really. The encounters can really add spice to a campaign. I've only used a few of the encounters in a campaign I ran but it sure was handy.

Answer (score 1):

[Of Dice and Dragons](http://ofdiceanddragons.com/encounter-ideas/), a blog by Scot Newbury, has some really nice ideas for encounters, organized by creature or featured NPC, you happen to need. Most are non-combat.

It's worth a look :)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I have also found *Book of Lairs 2*, which seems to get slightly better reviews than *Book of Lairs 1*, primarily due to the larger number of authors writing the encounters.  Also, there are good reviews of Mongoose's *Book of Encounters and Lairs*.  Unlike the TSR books of lairs that go up to about level 10, Mongoose's book goes up to about level 20.